# Return list of True/ False bool value for list of leap years given as an argument

Tags: python, function, leap-year

I have to check whether year = [1900, 2020, 2021, 2001] is a leap year or not and get True/False as a result (Boolean)

I have written a function as :

```
def is_leap_year(year):
   return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

But now I need to pass a list as year = [1900, 2020, 2021, 2001] and when I am doing so I am getting an error as "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'"

How do I pass a list as an argument in a function?

Comment: You're passing a list into a function that expects an ```int``` as a parameter.

Comment: You have a function that does it for one value. You just need to apply that function to a list of values in a loop.

Comment: If you want to check the whole list: ```return all(years%4==0 and (years % 100 != 0 or years % 400 == 0) for years in year)```

Comment: "How do I pass a list as an argument in a function?" You already did do that. The problem is that the function isn't written to work with lists, it expects just integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can simply do this:**

```
def is_leap_year(year):
   return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
years = [1900, 2020, 2021, 2001]
print(list(map(is_leap_year,years)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_leap_year(year):
   return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
year = [1900, 2020, 2021, 2001]
leap_year = list(map(is_leap_year,year))
print(leap_year)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(year)):
    print(is_leap_year(year[i])
```